Can a video game developer restrict how people stream game content?
I've recently come across this page published by the developers of the game Tsukihime. These "guidelines" state the following:

Please be sure to follow the provisions listed below when creating, uploading, or streaming gameplay videos.
Allowed Content

All episodes of Arcueid’s route and up until the opening of Ciel’s route
The soundtracks used for the opening animation in both routes and the ending for the Arcueid’s route are not covered by this guideline, and we ask that each content creator mutes the audio for copyright purposes.

GALLERY Mode

Other than the areas listed in the “Prohibited Content”

Prohibited Content
The following will not be permitted for streaming:

Ciel’s route and onward
Ending credits of Ciel’s route
Teach Me, Miss Ciel 15 - 22 and 25

The following in GALLERY Mode:

Ending list of Ciel’s route
Flowchart of Ciel’s route
Parts of the scenario that relate to the Ciel’s route and onward

Video Content
Videos may NOT include:

Raw playthrough without any additional content, such as the streamer’s commentary or review.
Content that damages the credibility or reputation of the people involved in the production of the game.
Content that suggests that the content creator is sponsored by or affiliated with the production of the game.
Content obtained via illegal access and/or content that affirms or encourages unauthorized access, acquisition, modification, or alteration of the game’s data.
Content that includes intellectual property rights owned by a third party without obtaining permission.
Obscenity, violence, or anything produced by the content creator that can be considered morally offensive.
Content that violates local laws and regulations.
Other content that Aniplex of America deems inappropriate.

Regarding Social Media Posts

Please clearly include spoiler warnings in any content so as not to prevent viewers and other players from enjoying the game themselves.
Materials of this game and any content created using the materials cannot be used for money making purposes or to gain any financial benefit except through official monetization program provided by approved video content services such as YouTube and Twitch.

Others

These guidelines are subject to revision without notice.
Videos uploaded after any guideline revisions must conform to the revised guidelines.
This guideline is only applied to personal use and streaming. If any corporate entity (or content creators contracted with a corporate entity, entertainment agency, production company, etc.) wishes to upload content listed in this guideline, please contact us at:
contact@aniplexusa.com
Due to the volume of the inquiries, we may not answer each inquiry pertaining to the regulation set forth in this guideline and its application to your video content.


It seems to me as if the developers quite unilaterally decide for the consumer what they can and can not stream. How enforceable would such "guidelines" actually be, legally speaking?

I'm primarily interested in answers regarding the european-union and the united-states, but other jurisdictions are welcome.

"we ask that each content creator mutes the audio for copyright purposes."  I don't understand how if you are streaming a game that muting the audio would prevent a copyright violation.

@MichaelHall If the game itself has audio licensed from another source (music, or stock sound effects maybe), they will generally pay for permission to play it during the game to the player, but not the much higher sum for permission to stream it to whoever happens to be listening. Many games with licensed music have a "streaming mode" that specifically removes that music for this reason.

More examples: Live Streaming and Video/Image Posting Guidelines for
FINAL FANTASY VII REBIRTH, Atlus - Streaming Guidelines Archives

See this Q&A for a related issue. Streaming video game content is something that would be likely litigated with a "fair use" exception by the defense.  But these cases never get far in courts because the parties settle, or the companies avoid bringing them for simple PR reasons.  Nintendo once tried to be heavy-handed with it, but now they and many others officially permit streaming provided you abide by certain rules.  These would fit the same general rubric.

"we ask that each content creator mutes the audio for copyright purposes." I don't understand why you do not put a streamer mode into your game, that automatically mutes it...

I wonder, what makes you think it would not be allowed? Yes, most developers allow streaming (because it's free marketing for them), but surely a developer who sees things differently is free to choose not to allow it? Honestly I'm more surprised that this kind of thing doesn't happen more often with more cinematic / movie-like games. I have personally sometimes watched playthroughs of games because then I didn't need to play them myself anymore, e.g., to follow the storyline of a sequel.

@infinitezero This is a visual novel game.  A remake and translation of a visual novel game.  From like 80's Japan.  One of the great classics of the medium, to be sure.  But not a game genre one usually associates with providing lots of user features, or studios willing or able to throw extra money at it.  The studios are usually shoe-stringing their budget even if they don't need to (Tsukihime was one of the original properties in what became a very successful franchise and setting, though it was another title that really propelled it upwards).

The creators of the word "the" prohibit its use in anything they deem inappropriate. These guidelines are subject to revision without notice. Violations will considered admissions of guilt. Settlements may be obtained by purchasing the creator a beer.

@Cadence: I suspect that the makers of the game might actually prefer that streamers let their audience hear the material, since it may make viewers more likely to buy the game, but they need to "officially" discourage it to avoid being liable for any third-party violation of third-party copyrights.

Note that regardless of whether you would prevail from a legal standpoint, you might run into problems with your stream platform, due to the tendency to overly trust claims.  Famously Hololive had huge swathes of the games they played struck, causing them to private almost all of their old videos (although they're based in Japan, so slightly different rules).  Other streamers have had similar issues, and too many strikes on places like YouTube can end a career there...

The default rule is that a holder of a copyright may license reproduction of the work on such terms as the copyright holder deems fit. Effectively, the copyright holder is providing users with more rights than they would have in the absence of this license.
Unless the first sale doctrine applies, the default rule applies here and this is allowed. The nature of the underlying product in the question is a bit sketchy, so while it seems like the first sale rule would not apply to this streaming content, it is hard to tell.

Something to note is on the PlayStation 4/5 they will block streaming/recording during various cutscenes when using the built in tools.

@JoeW I haven't played video games in 40 years and have no idea what any of that means.

@JoeW and legally? Technical means are irrelevant, relevant is what you are allowed to do.

What it means is they use code to enforce what can and can’t be streamed instead of just asking people to not stream certain parts.

@Trish I can’t comment on that, I was just mentioning that games can and do block streaming at the software/hardware level already.

@JoeW If they do that, and you try to override it, you might be violating the DMCA.

@JoeW Since they have the right to prohibit these activities, they can also implement technical measures to make it difficult. This is little different from implementing copy-protection on game media.

@Barmar that was the entire point of my comment that blocking of content is already happening.

@Barmar I am sure you know this already, but for completeness: even if they do not have the right to prohibit those activities, circumventing digital locks is not allowed. i.e. even if the use was known in advance to be a fair use, breaking DRM of a copyrighted work is still illegal.

That does not seem to be unconditionally true, @preferred_anon. See https://www.techdirt.com/2014/01/23/europes-highest-court-says-drm-circumvention-may-be-lawful-certain-circumstances/ and https://www.pcgamer.com/us-congress-deems-it-legal-to-circumvent-drm-to-repair-electronic-devices/, for example.  It will vary by jurisdiction, and it's unclear (to me) whether the question is altogether settled in any jurisdiction.

@JohnBollinger Interesting links! I intended to cover the US only (since Barmar mentioned the DMCA). I had no idea about exemptions in that case, thanks.

@Barmar At least in the US, it's substantially different from implementing copy-protection on game media. US copyright law is very specific that it is not a violation of copyright to make a copy of a computer program for backup purposes (and in normal use). There are, thus, explicit actions of copying such game media which are not violations of copyright, while other actions of copying the same media are violations of copyright. In other words, copying such media may or may not be a violation of copyright, depending on the reason for copying.

@Makyen Since there's no way for the vendor to know which copies are purely for backup and which are for giving to your friends, they just prevented all copies.
